# Flutter Like Button Animation Not Working After Adding Method

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am using the like_button package from this repository (https://pub.dev/packages/like_button) in my Flutter application. The like button animation was working fine under normal conditions. However, after I added a method to be executed when the button is pressed, the animation stopped working as expected.

I can confirm that the method is working properly, but the frontend animation of the like button is not working. It seems to be related to this method, as the animation works fine without it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async {
    print('pressed');

    await toggleFavorite();
    print(success);

    return !isLiked;

    /// if failed, you can do nothing
    // return success? !isLiked:isLiked;
  }



Future<void> toggleFavorite() async {
    if (favorites.contains(current)) {
      favorites.remove(current);
    } else {
      favorites.add(current);
    }
    print(favorites);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The toggleFavorite() function, which is an asynchronous function that performs some operation. After adding this method, the like button animation stopped working. But the function is working properly and I can see the output.

Comment: what do you mean with "animation not working" , is it to fast, to slow, doesn't appear anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thoroughly debugging and analyzing the code, I discovered that the Like Button was functioning smoothly when I commented out the line `notifyListeners()` in the `toggleFavorite()` method.

However, when I uncommented `notifyListeners()` in the `toggleFavorite()` method, it triggered a rebuild of the UI by notifying the listeners of the state change, which should reflect the updated state of the favorites list. This behaviour somehow affected the like-button action.

Further investigation revealed that the issue was with the `onLikeButtonTapped()` method, which was initially defined inside the `MyAppState` class, a subclass of `ChangeNotifier`. Moving the `onLikeButtonTapped()` method outside the `MyAppState` class and defined inside its widget class resolved the problem.

It is important to carefully review the placement and accessibility of methods when working with ChangeNotifier and notifyListeners() in Flutter apps. By identifying the root cause and luck, I was able to resolve the issue.